# scipy modulenotfound error

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, scikit-learn, pycharm

I am using python 3.7 in a virtual env. I have made sure that I am using the correct interpreter for the project. I have made sure that the package is installed in the pycharm settings. I can even import in the cell and intellisense filled out options for me. Any ideas as to why I am getting the infamous module not found error?[image]

edit:
Out of curiosity I went to the directory of where python 3.7 in installed and tried to install scipy. It worked there and all of the sudden it worked in pycharm. My question has now morphed into if the interpreter for a project is in the virtual env. why is it looking at my installation version instead?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. I was using an interpreter close to the same name from a previous attempt at the project. My project is called blog not blog tutorial. My issue was fixed after I changed interpreters